# Number of elements in a finite group satisfies the given equation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

In a finite group the number of **non  identity** elements which satisfy the given equation.$$ x^n =e$$. Where $e$ is identity. 
My efforts:
If $n$ is prime then the number of elements are $multiple \ of \ (n-1) $. I generalised it by some examples. 
If n is not prime then what are the number of elements. Is it true that it will be a multiple of $\phi (n)$. If yes then how. 
Anyone can help.

Comment: Does $n$ have any relation to the number of elements in the group?

Comment: @Arthur no n is just exponent i.e. belongs to natural number

Comment: Well, any group of $4$ elements and $n = 4$ shows you that $\phi(n)$ is not involved, at least not as directly as you propose, since there are three solutions and $\phi(4) = 2$. In fact, if $n$ is the number of elements in the group, then $x^n = e$ is true for _any_ element in the group, so there are always $n-1$ solutions.

Comment: @Arthur assumed that no of elements are larger than exponent. Example number of elements in a finite group with equation $x^4=e$ are multiple of 2 or 3or anything else?

Comment: If $k$ is large then $S_k$ contains a lot of $4-$ cycles.  More simply, just take a big product of cyclic groups of order $4$.

Comment: @lulu  lets modify the question the number of elements in a finite group with satisfy the equation $x^6=e$ will be?

Comment: Nothing in what I wrote was specific to $4$.  You can replace it with any exponent you like.

Comment: @Arthur if $x^5=e$ then the number of elements are multiple of 4n. Similiarly what can we say about number of elements if $x^6=e$?

Comment: @lulu if $x^5=e$ then the number of elements are multiple of 4n. Similiarly what can we say about number of elements if $x^6=e$? For $x^5=e$ this is the question of Joesph Gallian. I want to find the number of elements that satisfy $x^6=e$

Comment: The only result I am aware of along the lines you are asking is an old theorem of Frobenius which says that, assuming $n$ divides the order of a group, then the number of solutions to $g^n=e$ in the group is a multiple of $n$.  See, for example, [this](http://www.pitt.edu/~gmc/ch1/node7.html)

Comment: @lulu thnks for sharing. But sorry. At present i only read the starting to chapters of Gallian book so i didnt get the stuff you shared. At present can u please tell me the number if elemnets which satisfy the given equation i.e  example $x^6=e$ will be multiple of $2$?

Comment: Yes, that number will be a multiple of $6$ (by the Theorem I cited).

Comment: @lulu if multiple of 6 then it is failed for prime number. But for prime number i am definitely sure that it is multiple of (p-1). That is for example$ x^11=e$ the number of elemnts are multiple of 10. If  $x^6=e$ the according to you number of elemnts are multiple of 6. Please can you prove it.

Comment: What do you mean "failed for prime number"? In the cyclic group of order $p$ there are exactly $p$ solutions to $x^p=e$.  in particular, in the cyclic group of order $11$, there are $11$ solutions to $x^{11}=e$.

Comment: @lulu i appologies that i am not getting you because i am new to algebra . Can you please explain the number of elements which satisfy $x^6=e$ are multiple of 6 and what are they. For example $x^3=e$ has number of elements that are multiple of 2. And the elements are $x,x^2$. Can you list the elements for $x^6=e$ as i listed?

Comment: I think we are talking at cross purposes.  You keep writing about the equation $x^k=e$ but perhaps you mean to write about the number of elements of order exactly $k$.  These are related concepts, obviously, but they are not equivalent. It is not true that the number of solutions to $x^3=e$ is a multiple of $2$.  In the cyclic group of order $3$ there are $3$ solutions.

Comment: @lulu please see this. Read "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845453/show-that-number-of-solutions-satisfying-x5-e-is-a-multiple-of-4"

Comment: Exactly.  That question specifies "non-identity".  I am speaking of the total number of solutions, with no exclusions.  For primes, that's just a matter of adding or subtracting $1$.  For composites, you have to be clear what you are excluding.

Comment: @lulu see my question i highlighted $non identity$ elements. Anyway can you please tell me the number of non identity elements which satisfy $x^4=e$. I generalised for prime exponents. Can we generalised for non prime exponents or not. I hope at this time you will get me.

Comment: All we know is the Frobenius theorem.  The number of solutions to $x^4=e$ is divisible by $4$.  Call that number $4k$.  $4k-1$ is not necessarily divisible by $3$.  In the quaternion group of order $8$, there are $7$ solutions to $x^4=e$, excluding $x=e$.

Comment: @lulu in your $7$ solutions is it include identity? If yes then the non identity  solutions are 6 and which is mutiple of phi(6). If identity is not included then i am satisfied by you and the conversation closed here.

Comment: It is not included.  The group is non-cyclic (not even abelian) so every element in the group satisfies $x^4=e$.  Excluding the identity that means there are exactly $7$ solutions.

Comment: @lulu thankyou for explaining and giving your precious time. Now i got it that my generalisation is wrong.